# show FacesMessage when invoking wizard.getOldStep()

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to show a `FacesMessage` built in `onFlowProcess` of a primefaces wizard.

```
public String onFlowProcess(FlowEvent event) {  
    if (event.getOldStep().equalsIgnoreCase("otherTab")){
        if (!hasImage){
            FacesUtils.addMessage(null, "Error", "image is required", FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            return event.getOldStep();
        }
    }
    return event.getNewStep();
}
```

The message should be send to the growl but I believe that by invoking `getOldStep()`, the message is lost along the way.

My growl is declared as :

```
<p:growl life="2500" showDetail="true" globalOnly="true"/>
```

and the wizard contains `flowListener="#{bean.onFlowProcess}"`.

I tried to keep my `FacesMessage` with

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
```

but this seems to work only for page redirect...

If anybody has any idea... Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating the `<p:growl>` from the bean:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:growl");
```